# Code works in php 5.5 needs a rewrite for 5.3

Tags: php

I have a snippet of code that works great on php 5.5 but doen'st work on 5.3.
I have some of it figured out but not all. there is still an unexpected "[" in the logs.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$params = [
    'field_oem_value' => $oemSearch,
    'field_oem_pn_value' => $oempnSearch
  ];    

// The "previous" link
$prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?'. http_build_query($params + ['page' => 1]) .'" title="First page" class="pagination">&laquo;</a> <a href="?' . http_build_query($params + ['page' => $page-1]) . '" title="Previous page" class="pagination">&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';

// The "next" link
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?' . http_build_query($params + ['page' => $page+1]) . '" title="Next page" class="pagination">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?' . http_build_query($params + ['page' => $pages]) . '" title="Last page" class="pagination">&raquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';

// Display the paging info
echo '<div id="paging"><p class="pagination">', $prevlink, ' Page ', $page, ' of ', $pages, ' pages, displaying ', $start, '-', $end, ' of ', $total, ' results ', $nextlink, ' </p></div>';
```

I can rewrite the first part:

```
  $params = array(
    'field_oem_value' => $oemSearch,
    'field_oem_pn_value' => $oempnSearch
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP 5.3 is no [short array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

Change `['page' => $page-1]` to `array('page' => $page-1)`